# Vim-Tiny renamed?

Tags: package-management, vim

Why is the Vim-Tiny package renamed to Vim.Tiny once it is installed?

> /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Just curious about naming conventions in Ubuntu -- do many packages change names when installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name remains `vim-tiny` after installation (run `dpkg -l | grep vim`), but the name of the program distributed within that package is vim.tiny.

It is quite clear why the package cannot be called "vim.tiny": package names follow a convention in which dots and underscores have special meanings, but a dash can be a part of a package name.

On the other hand, the vim releases follow another convention, where dashes separate the program name from the release versions (like "vim-7.3-src.tar.gz"). I guess that this is the reason why the contents (vim.tiny) has a different name than the package that wraps it (vim-tiny).